# Can't find variable: alasql (in PhoneGap app for iOS) - alasql 0.2.0

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, alasql

If I run the "app" in Chrome on my pc as http, everything works as expected with [alasql](http://alasql.org) but after the app is built by PhoneGap Build the alasql functions are not available.

All javascript is called after 'deviceready' in the app (but in the $(document).ready() in the Chrome test).

index.html links to these scripts (among others):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dist/alasql.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

And in index.js I have a function that is called from `ondeviceready` (in index.html):

```
alasql('CREATE localStorage DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db'); //THIS IS WERE THE ERROR OCCURS
alasql('ATTACH localStorage DATABASE db');
alasql('USE db');
```

I've reinstalled the app but no success. Still getting the same error. Everything else works fine. Any ideas?